# requests session.close() does not close the session

Tags: python, python-requests

I expected calling close() on a Session object to close the session. But looks like that's not happening. Am I missing something?

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://google.com'
r = s.get(url)
s.close()
print("s is closed now")
r = s.get(url)
print(r)
```

output:

```
s is closed now
<Response [200]>
```

The second call to s.get() should have given an error.

Comment: Do you wish to go back or is it different url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the [implementation for `Session.close()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/requests/sessions/) we can find that:

```
def close(self):
    """Closes all adapters and as such the session"""
    for v in self.adapters.values():
        v.close()
```

And inside the [`adapter.close` implementation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/requests/adapters/):

```
   def close(self):
        """Disposes of any internal state.

        Currently, this closes the PoolManager and any active ProxyManager,
        which closes any pooled connections.
        """
        self.poolmanager.clear()
        for proxy in self.proxy_manager.values():
            proxy.clear()
```

So what I could make out is that, it clears the state of the `Session` object. So in case you have logged in to some site and have some stored cookies in the `Session`, then these cookies will be removed once you use the `session.close()` method. The inner functions still remain functional though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the question is how do I close the session. I don't want to use context manager because I make requests at different places in my code and want to close the session before the script ends.

Comment: @AhteshamAkhtar  Maybe close and delete the `Session` object?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Context Manager to auto-close it:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://google.com'
    r = s.get(url)
```

See [requests docs > Sessions](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> This will make sure the session is closed as soon as the with block is exited, even if unhandled exceptions occurred.

Comment: That won't destroy the session object though and you can still call s.get afterwards. Event if it's (unquestionnably) a better practice than in the question, it doesn't help to understand what is going on here.